# How to invoke a method in a second class, inside the main method, to execute an action in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I am building an Interactive-Fiction-Game in Java, but am having a trouble using a second class to be used in the main class. I am using Eclipse.
Here is my main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cmdIF;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;


        out.print("Welcome to the world! Which way do you want to go?");
        String northD = "You walk into a forest.";
        if(x=1) {
            out.print(northD);
        }
        cmdIF = input.nextLine();
        choosePath();   
    }
    public void choosePath(actionClass cmdCenter) {
          actionClass.cmdCenter();
    }
}
```

And the class that contains the method:

```
public class actionClass {
    public void cmdCenter() {
        if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("NORTH") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO NORTH")) { out.println(northD); x++; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("EAST") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO EAST")) { out.println(eastD); y++; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("SOUTH") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO SOUTH")) { out.println(southD); x--; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("WEST") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO WEST")) { out.println(westD); y--; }
        else { out.println("You can't do that."); }

    }
}
```

Whenever I execute the code I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The method choosePath(actionClass) in the type mainClass is
>   not applicable for the arguments ()
>
> at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:14)

How can I make these methods work together?

Comment: on your main method, you called `choosePath()` without any arguments. Your defined `choosePath` method is actually expecting an argument `actionClass`, so when you call your method, it has to be `choosePath(actionClass)`.

Comment: You ran your program even it has compile errors.

Comment: +jmpg I tried running using `choosePath(actionClass)` but I got this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: `Unresolved compilation problem: 
 actionClass cannot be resolved to a variable

 at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:14)`

Comment: Plus, 'String cmdIF' is of local scope to the main method and not visible to a method of actionClass unless passed in as a parameter

Comment: +paisanco I could fix that if it the compiler would even acknowledge that I wanted to invoke the method.

Comment: @SputnicK well you got that error because you dont have an `actionClass` on your `Main` method. if you go ahead and create one (i.e. `actionClass myActionClass = new actionClass();` then you can use it to call your method: `choosePath(myActionClass );`

Comment: +jmpg I tried that and got this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method choosePath(actionClass, String) in the type mainClass is not applicable for the arguments (actionClass)

 at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:15)`

Comment: change cmdCenter to `public static void cmdCenter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first step you access the method like this

```
actionClass.cmdCenter();
```

is not `static` so just make `cmdCenter` *static*  like this

```
public static void cmdCenter
```

and `choosePath()` have *parameter*  so you have to use it like this `choosePath(actionClass)` and since you use it in `static` method you have to create instance or make `choosePath` static

```
  public static void choosePath(actionClass)
```

but you don't have to just remove `paramater` from `choosePath`

```
   //public void choosePath(actionClass cmdCenter) {
     public static void choosePath()
```

and seems you have to pass `x` and `y` variable to `cmdCenter` too so its become like this

```
public static void cmdCenter(String cmdIF, int x, int y)
```

and rest the code its fine

---

fixed version of your code :

```
public class Main {


    static String cmdIF;
    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Welcome to the world! Which way do you want to go?");
        String northD = "You walk into a forest.";
        if(x ==1) {
            System.out.print(northD);
        }
        cmdIF = input.nextLine();
        choosePath();
    }
    public static void choosePath() {
        actionClass.cmdCenter(cmdIF, x, y);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class actionClass {
    public static void cmdCenter(String cmdIF, int x, int y) {
        if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("NORTH") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO NORTH")) { out.println("GO NORTH"); x++; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("EAST") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO EAST")) { out.println("GO EAST"); y++; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("SOUTH") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO SOUTH")) { out.println("GO SOUTH"); x--; }
        else if(cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("WEST") || cmdIF.equalsIgnoreCase("GO WEST")) { out.println("GO WEST"); y--; }
        else { System.out.println("You can't do that."); }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `cmdCenter()` method in `actionClass` to be declared as:

```
public void cmdCenter(String cmdIF)
```

Then change `choosePath()` to be

```
public void choosePath(actionClass action, String cmdIf) {
    action.cmdCenter(cmdIf);
}
```

and obviously change your `main()` method's call to `choosePath()` appropriately.  And you'll need to `new` up an instance of `actionClass` to pass into `choosePath()`.

Comment: "_and obviously change your main() method's call to choosePath() appropriately. And you'll need to new up an instance of actionClass to pass into choosePath()._" - What exactly do you mean by that? I followed your other steps and used choosePath(actionClass) but still am getting an error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 actionClass cannot be resolved to a variable

 at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:15)
`